# Why there are collection of static constructors in ITypeSymbol instead of one?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Today working with Roslyn I've stumbled on `StaticConstructors` property of ITypeSymbol and it's declared as `ImmutableArray<IMethodSymbol>` but as far as I know there could be maximum one static constructor both in C# and VB. The question is why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess: partial classes.

```
public partial class Foo
{
    static Foo() {}
}

public partial class Foo
{
    static Foo() {}
}
```

Even though that's not valid code (which I'd previously forgotten) it may need to be represented within Roslyn's object model. If you can get at an `ITypeSymbol` for `Foo` while this code is *being* compiled, you may find both of the static constructors there.

Comment: Compilation error: Type 'Tests.Foo' already defines a member called '.cctor' with the same parameter types

Comment: @PavelKrymets: Hmm. Had forgotten that. Can you get a type symbol for something that doesn't compile?

Comment: Yes, you are right, there are two constructors in there.

Answer (score -1):

Static Constructor overloads, there could be other ones take parameters.

Comment: The static constructor cannot take a parameter because you never call it manually.